# How can I run `gpg` as non-root user, from a Chef cookbook?

Tags: linux, permissions, chef-infra

I need to import via Chef [client, 13], a public key in all the users of a [Ubuntu 14.04] system.

I'm finding, though, very strange ownership behaviors, and I can't figure out how to solve them; the following is a list of what happens with different approaches (all the snippets are blocks inside a `bash` resource`.

1.This will execute gpg as `<login>`, but will try to write to /root/.gnupg:

```
code "gpg --import << PUBKEY..."
user login
```

2.This will (sometimes) create `/home/<login>/.gnupg` with  owner, then will create inside it the data files with root owner, then will try to write to them as `<login>`:

```
code "sudo -iu #{login} gpg --import << PUBKEY..."
```

3.Executing #2 manually via terminal works as expected

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: I see; then definitely, this question should be moved to devops.stackexchange.com. There is a long history of chef questions on stackoverflow.com, which is misleading (see for example, the `Related` links).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's off-topic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add `environment 'HOME' => "/home/#{login}"` to the `bash` resource. The `gpg` command line tool uses this variable rather than actually checking what directory is the current user's homedir. When you run using `sudo -i`, a login shell is created for the user which sets this environment variable.